# Progress bar in windows form c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar, windows-forms-designer

Im litterly just starting out in the world of c# and creating windows applications.

Ive created a small program that uses a button to launch a batch file.

The batch file takes files in a folder and encrypts them 1 by 1 (there are 14000 files). For each file that the batch program encrypts,it creates a new file with a different extention in the same folder. So when the program finishes there are 28000 files...

What I would love to add a progress bar to my windows form but do not know where to start in regards to the code to make it read the number of files left to process or how many new files are left to create.

If anyone can advise or let me know which part of my code it share to help let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _the number of files_ Look at System.IO.Directory's methods!

Comment: You could use a Timer to periodically poll the folder, using methods such as TaW suggested.  Another approach might be to use the [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1) to detect when files are added to the folder.

Comment: So using the look at method with a timer can link that to the progress bar to meet the max at 2800 files? Or with the FileSystemWatcber detecting each file with max on the progress bar set at the 2800 files

Comment: Um, it is not a 'LookAtMethod' : I meant have a look at the various function the Directory class offers! Fint the count before and count again at each tick..

Comment: Ahh I get you haha. Told you I was just starting out. I will look through the Directory and have a play. I really appreciate your input